Big number subtraction, abs value from negative result
I need help to fix the C++ Visual Studio x64 program below which should subtract two big numbers and print abs value of the result.
The subtraction result is -0xf9084d7a11528273377bf8560b3ffe
I assume that abs value should be 2s complement i.e. 0x06f7b285eead7d8cc88407a9f4c001
I'm I right? How to fix the program to calculate the correct result.
Note this is just a test program. I will work with arbitrary big numbers stored in uint64_t chunks.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring> // For memset

// Function to add a small value to a big integer array
void add_small_value(uint64_t* data, uint64_t value, size_t length) {
    uint64_t carry = value;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        uint64_t temp = data[i] + carry;
        carry = (temp < data[i]) ? 1 : 0;
        data[i] = temp;
        if (carry == 0) break;
    }
}

// Function to subtract big integer B from A: result = A - B
bool big_integer_special_subtract(uint64_t* A, uint64_t* B, uint64_t* result, size_t len) {
    uint8_t borrow = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        borrow = _subborrow_u64(borrow, A[i], B[i], &result[i]);
    }
    if (borrow == 1) {
        uint64_t carry = 1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            // XOR operation (invert bits)
            result[i] ^= ULLONG_MAX;

            // Add carry
            uint64_t temp = result[i] + carry;
            carry = (temp < result[i]) ? 1 : 0;  // Check for carry
            result[i] = temp;
        }
        //add_small_value(result, 1, len);
    }
    return (borrow == 1) ? true : false;
}

// Function to print the data array as a hexadecimal number
void printHex(const uint64_t* data, size_t length) {
    bool leadingZero = true;
    for (size_t i = length; i > 0; --i) {
        if (leadingZero) {
            if (data[i - 1] != 0) {
                std::cout << std::hex << data[i - 1];
                leadingZero = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << std::hex << data[i - 1];
        }
    }
    if (leadingZero) {
        std::cout << "0";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    const size_t length = 2; // Two 64-bit chunks (for large numbers)

    // The two 64-bit chunks for the values A and B
    uint64_t A[length] = { 0xcc88407a9f4c002, 0x306f7b285eead7d8 };
    uint64_t B[length] = { 0, 0x4000000000000000 }; // B is large and needs to be represented across two chunks
    uint64_t result[length];

    std::cout << "A (in hex): 0x";
    printHex(A, length);

    std::cout << "B (in hex): 0x";
    printHex(B, 2); // We are printing two chunks for B

    bool isNegative = big_integer_special_subtract(A, B, result, length);

    if (isNegative) {
        std::cout << "Result (A - B) was negative, absolute value (in hex): 0x";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Result (A - B) was positive (in hex): 0x";
    }
    printHex(result, length);

    return 0;
}


For arbitrarily large numbers you probably want to look into using a library like GMP.

0x06f7b285eead7d8cc88407a9f4c001 is not a negation of -0xf9084d7a11528273377bf8560b3ffe. If nothing else, this should be obvious from the fact that one is odd and the other is even (which in turn could be determined just looking at the last digit), whereas x and -x would both be odd or both even, for any x.

@Caster The substatement of this if statement     if (leadingZero) {
std::cout << "0";
} is never executed.:) In this point leadingZero is always equal to false.

Out of curiosity, in C++, where are you passing a big integer around as a raw uint64_t * (which, presumably, represents the first character of an array of uint64_t)?    Why not represent your big integer using a class type (say MyBigThumpingInteger) and pass that as arguments to functions?   Wrapping the logic in a class means no need to expose the internal working to unrelated functions and it is also possible to pick reasonable ways of passing as arguments (by value, by reference, etc).

The function is a part of Lucas-Lehmer Primality Testing. I am going to test the Marsenne Prime  2^136279841 - 1 which has 41,024,320 decimal digits. Storing this number in binary (i.e. 136,279,841 "1") in "raw" RAM is the easiest way how to work with it. You need 2,129,373 uint64_t chunks.

if (a > b) return a-b; return b-a;

Either try a well organized big number library like boost.mutilprecission or use std::vector to avoid memory management problems.
